# How to solve $z(s) + \int_0^s \int_t^3 z(\tau) d \tau dt = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I usually use laplace transform,

It is clear that $z(0) = 1$
if we differentiate once we get

$\dot{z}(s) + \int_s^3 z(\tau) d\tau = 0$

But this implies that 
$\dot{z}(0) = -\int_0^3 z(\tau) d\tau$ right?

I'm not sure how to continue!

Differentiating again we get

$\ddot{z}(s) - z(s) = 0$

But how to get the second initial condition?

we have $z\in L_2[0,3]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ddot z(s) = z(s)$, we see that $z=a e^{-t} + b e^t$ is the general form of the solution to your equation. Now we must determine $a$ and $b$.

We know already that $z(0)=1$. Thus $a+b=1$.

We also know that since $$\dot z(s) = - \int_s^3 z(\tau)d\tau,$$ we have $\dot z(3) = 0$.

Thus $\dot z(t) = -a e^{-t} + b e^{t}$ and $\dot z(3) = -a e^{-3} + b e^3 = 0$ which means $$-a + b e^{6} = 0.$$

Adding the two equations gives $b+b e^{6} = 1$ and $b = (1+e^6)^{-1}$.

Finally we have $a = 1-(1+e^6)^{-1}$ and we have determined $z$.

---

One approach to solving a homogenous differential equation is by substituting $z(t) = e^{rt}$ for an unknown (possibly complex) $r$.

Thus we see that $\ddot z = z$ turns into $$r^2 e^{rt}=e^{rt}$$ we can cancel $e^{rt}$ to find a requirement on $r$,
$$r^2 =1$$ which tells us that $r=\pm 1$.

Thus we see that if $z_1 = e^{-t}$ or $z_2=e^{t}$, then $z_1$ and $z_2$ are solutions to the differential equation. Since $\ddot z = z$ is a linear differential equation, any function of the form $z=az_1 + bz_2$ is a solution of the differential equation as well. Finally since this is a linear second order differential equation, every function in the space of solutions is a linear combination of two linearly independent solutions. $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ are linearly independent, therefore the only solutions to $$\ddot z = z$$ are the functions $$z=ae^{-t} + be^t.$$

Comment: That was nice Joel. Thanks. Since I did not work on ODEs since ages, I don't remember why your first sentence holds. Why it should have the form $z=ae^{-t} + b e^{t}$ ? Is it easy to prove?

Comment: I added a section to my post describing how to find the solution. I am glad I could help :)